# How to fix Lost connection to mysql system error:1?

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert

While trying to insert my data into MySQL using python with mysql.connector module, I came up with an error which is "Lost connection to MySQL server at '127.0.0.1:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2471)" Thanks for help.

Comment: this comes when one timeout is reached.

Comment: I set the timeout value to a very high number actually.

Comment: there are actually more than one timeout, sp maybe you have the wrong one

Comment: I changed the one which is mysql->edit->preferences->sql editor dbms timeouts and mysql->edit->preferences->ssh timeouts. Is there any other timeouts I need to change